# How to iterate a JsonObject (gson)

Tags: java, json, gson, json-deserialization

I have a JsonObject e.g

```
JsonObject jsonObject = {"keyInt":2,"keyString":"val1","id":"0123456"}
```

Every `JsonObject` contains a `"id"` entry, but the number of other key/value pairs is NOT determined, so I want to create create an object with 2 attributes:

```
class myGenericObject {
  Map<String, Object> attributes;
  String id;
}
```

So I want my attributes map to look like this:

```
"keyInt" -> 4711
"keyStr" -> "val1"
```

I found this solution

```
Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = jsonObject.entrySet();
for(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : entrySet){
  attributes.put(entry.getKey(), jsonObject.get(entry.getKey()));
}
```

but the values are enclosed by `""`

```
"keyInt" -> "4711"
"keyStr" -> ""val1""
```

How to get the plain values (`4711` and `"val1"`)?

Input data:

```
{
  "id": 0815, 
  "a": "a string",
  "b": 123.4,
  "c": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": true,
    "c": ["a", "b", "c"]
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  "id": 4711, 
  "x": false,
  "y": "y?",
}
```

Comment: Yes, I could cut the first and last character ("), but this would be rather a sad solution (or not?)

Answer (score 13):

replace "" with blank.

```
   Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = jsonObject.entrySet();
   for(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : entrySet){
    if (! nonProperties.contains(entry.getKey())) {
      properties.put(entry.getKey(), jsonObject.get(entry.getKey()).replace("\"",""));
    }
   }
```

Comment: that only "solves" the problem with ""val1"" but not with "4711"

Comment: use 'entry.getValue().getAsString()' intsead 'jsonObject.get(entry.getKey()).replace("\"","")';

Answer (score 5):

How are you creating your JsonObject? Your code works for me. Consider this

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
...
...
...
try{
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("keyInt", 2);
        jsonObject.addProperty("keyString", "val1");
        jsonObject.addProperty("id", "0123456");

        System.out.println("json >>> "+jsonObject);

        Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = jsonObject.entrySet();
        for(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : entrySet){
          attributes.put(entry.getKey(), jsonObject.get(entry.getKey()));
        }

        for(Map.Entry<String,Object> att : attributes.entrySet()){
            System.out.println("key >>> "+att.getKey());
            System.out.println("val >>> "+att.getValue());
            } 
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

And it is working fine. Now I am interested in knowing how you created that JSON of yours?

You can also try this (JSONObject)

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
...
...
...
try{
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"keyInt\":2,\"keyString\":\"val1\",\"id\":\"0123456\"}");
        System.out.println("JSON :: "+jsonObject.toString());

        Iterator<String> it  =  jsonObject.keys();
         while( it.hasNext() ){
             String key = it.next();
             System.out.println("Key:: !!! >>> "+key);
             Object value = jsonObject.get(key);
             System.out.println("Value Type "+value.getClass().getName());
            }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

Comment: Well, I do not create any JSON, I get it from a database.

Comment: Can you please paste the dump of what you get from the database(to the question)?

Answer (score 3):

Just make following changes...

```
Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = jsonObject.entrySet();
for(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : entrySet){
 attributes.put(entry.getKey(), jsonObject.get(entry.getKey()).getAsString());
}
```

"getAsString" will do the magic for u

Answer (score 2):

Your Map values are [`JsonElement`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html)s. Whenever you print a `JsonElement` (e.g. using a debugger) its [`toString()`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#toString--) method will be called - and since a `JsonElement` has many implementing classes the default `toString` implementation wraps the value in quotes to ensure correct JSON. To get the value as a normal, unwrapped `String`, simply call [`getAsString()`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#getAsString--):

```
JsonElement elem;
// ...
String value = elem.getAsString();
```

With your example:

```
Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = jsonObject.entrySet();
for(Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : entrySet){
  attributes.put(entry.getKey(), jsonObject.get(entry.getKey()).getAsString());
}
```

Note there are many other methods you can call on a `JsonElement` to produce other types.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why you want to do manual manipulation in the first place. GSON decode will simply leave those absent key/value pairs as default value (zero,null). And then you can process as you want.

Comment: I want to handle all incoming json (with a key "id" and an additional unknown number of key/value pairs) with just ONE (more or less generic) class, where all key/value pairs where key != "id" are stored in a HashMap. Atm I managed to do so, but every value is wrapped in ".