# Is JSON parsing or String parsing more expensive in Java?

Tags: java, json, gson, string-parsing

I'm trying to dynamically parse a lot of data in Java. In other words I have tons of different types of data so I am putting them in a String or a JSON String (via GSON) instead of doing:

```
switch(data){
case instanceof Class1:
     Class1 data = gson.fromJson(jsonString);
     //Do Stuff for class 1 layout
case instanceof Class2:
     Class2 data = gson.fromJson(jsonString);
etc.
```

So instead of doing this for 80 or so classes (which more may be added/removed/changed at any given time) I am planning to put the data in either a String or Json String and parse out the values (depth first).

I am on a low end PC (single core Atom processor) and am trying to reduce the amount of taxing I put on the CPU, so determining which would be faster... regex string manipulation with splits or using a recursive JSON parser.

Comment: Have you considered testing it?

Comment: Was attempting to avoid dual development if someone may know off the top of their head or have a better suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us discuss both the cases you have mentioned here:

**CASE 1:**
Creating instances for each and every json input using gson (mapped to a Class)

and

**CASE 2:** Create a Document (or similar type object) itself and try accessing data from there.

For Case 2, you don't need to write a parser yourself: there are parsers already available.
I'll just write down a jackson example here (There must be similar stuff available with gson as well):

```
String myJson = "{ \"type\" : \"foo\", \"class\" : 3 }";
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = objectMapper.readValue(myJson, JsonNode.class);
JsonNode type = node.get("type");
System.out.println(type.asText());
```

As per my experience, the performance difference hasn't been much in both these cases as the libraries handle the parsing quite efficiently but if you have a lot of different types of JSON, then it doesn't make any sense to create POJOs out of each and every JSON (So much mapping !!).

I have personally not worked with gson because of performance reasons like [this](http://tuhrig.de/jaxb-vs-gson-and-jackson/) but you can create what's called an ObjectMapper using jackson and use it quite efficiently. I assume there should be similar thing in gson as well.

The only downside would be that every field will now be accessible through a string input which might make your code a bit unreadable.

**EDIT:**

If you really wish to iterate through all the fields of the json, you'll have to do DFS ultimately, but parsing can still be avoided by using the `fields` method of the JsonNode.

`root.fields()` will return with an iterator with the  entries in it which can be then gracefully used as described in answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653813/jackson-json-get-node-name-from-json-tree).

Remember, similar stuff with different names will be available in gson too. :)

Comment: You are still going to have to create an instance of each class type. And you have to know the keys of the JSON. I am getting a JSON string that I know nothing about. I want to be able to handle that.

Comment: While handling, you will have to know the keys right?

Or else, if you go through the ObjectMapper (No fan of jackson but I dont know how gson works), you won't have to declare the classes is what I am saying, since your JSON structure might change... You can't go and create classes for every new JSON is what I thought is causing you the problem.
Also, You can actually iterate through the nodes, their values, arrays, etc. and basically access the object without having a rigidity on the JSON structure (No need to map it to a class anymore).

Comment: fields() iterator can be used as well, btw.. if you wish to go through all the nodes. Handling JSON with java is a it ugly.

Comment: Well I mean you don't really know or care about the keys. You know you just have to iterate over all the items in the JSON be it object, array, primitive whatever. I just want to get the String value of each item, I don't care what the key is in this scenario.

Comment: Perhaps I just don't know what a JsonNode is. I thought that equated to Class1 in my example. But if I could use node to iterate over the JSON without knowing the keys...

Comment: Yes, you can use the `fields()` method to do exactly that. Also, got https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428329/using-gson-to-deserialize-specific-json-field-of-an-object for gson as well :D

Comment: Thanks Parijat. I think this covers how to do it in GSON. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27964498/how-to-iterate-a-jsonobject-gson

Comment: @Tacitus86 glad I could help :)